# Expected Value of Mixture Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have never before encountered a "mixture distribution," so I have run into a little trouble trying to calculate the mean of this one:

Let $X_{a,b}$ be such that, for parameters $a \in (0,1)$ and $b \in \left( \max\{-1, -\frac{1-a}{a}\}, 1 \right)$, we have that $P(X_{a,b} = 0) = a$ and $P(X_{a,b} = k) = a(1-a)(1-b)(1-a+ab)^{k-1}$.

How would I go about finding $E[X_{a,b}]$?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your distribution is over the integers and not continuous over the reals, the expectation is $a(1-a)(1-b) \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \delta^{k-1}$ where $\delta = (1 - a + ab)$. If you want to solve the infinite sum, you can for example differentiate the series $1/(1- x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ term by term.

Comment: how would you find it?